# Finding transaction type in PayPal's API's

Tags: paypal, paypal-nvp

Is there a way to find the transaction type using PayPal's API's? I have reviewed the NVP docs a few times, but it appears the NVP documentation is not complete and I can't figure out how to find what the funding source was.

This is for an ecommerce website and we are wanting to find out if more fraudulent purchases occur with Credit Cards or funds from within a PayPal account. We assume credit card, but we are trying to lessen the number of checks we have to do on all purchases to verify they are legitimate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Fraud Management Filters? here..
[Fraud Management](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/fmf/integration-guide/FMFIntro/)
I'm not sure you can tell from the values returned if it was a credit card or paypal account, i.e. I'm not sure if the fraud filters are applicable for a paypal account payment?
There seems to be a lot more "effort" having the filters ON but you are reducing your exposure to fraud and could have the filter on for 10% of transactions instead of them all.